# Code in SAS not writing properly to named range in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, sas

I have a sas code that write data in a name range in excel 2010.  On my computer everything works fine but on another computer it always write data starting in the A1 cell...

We have ckeck the ODBC and they have the same configuration on both computer.

In Excel are there any options that must be on/off to work ? (ex. ActiveX, Macro...)

This is the code we use, we just change the ODBC and table name.

```
libname Test odbc datasrc="Test";

proc datasets lib = Test nolist;
    delete Range_Test;
quit;

data Test.Range_Test set mydata; run;

libname Test clear;
```

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Double check that it's not your typo (missing ; in the data statement).

Comment: Sorry for the typo but it's a copy paste of part of my code.  I write over 100 tables in the excel file but they are all writen on the same sheet in cell A1. On my computer the are all showing in their own range but not on the other computer.

Comment: Where is this writing to?  A local file (different for each PC) or a network-located file (same file for both PCs)?  If a local file, did you define the ranges there?

Comment: For me the file is a local file and all the range name are defined in the excel file.  I send him a copy of my file and he has it on a  network location but he is the only one who can access it